# XSLT: how to get a representative list of elements belonging to an element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform some data like this:

```
<word>
   <morph type="prefix">
      <item type="txt" lang="tmy-Latn">ne-</item>
      <item type="gls" lang="en">3p.POSS-</item>
      <item type="gls" lang="tpi" />
      <item type="msa" lang="en">pro</item>
   </morph>
   <morph type="stem">
      <item type="txt" lang="tmy-Latn">waŋ</item>
      <item type="msa" lang="en">noun</item>
   </morph>
</word>
<word>
  <morph>
    <item><item type="txt" lang="tmy-Latn">lil</item>
    <item type="gls" lang="en">go</item>
    <item type="msa" lang="en">verb</item>morph>
</word>
```

The relevant factors are that there are a bunch of `<morph>` elements which each have various child `<item>` elements. The thing is, for any given document some types of item elements might be entirely absent. Some may be present in only some of the morph elements. If they are present they might be empty anyway. And finally there might be more then one item of the same `@type` in one morph element, but then they will differ on their `@lang` attribute.

When I am transforming the document, I need a way to know what distinct item elements exist within that particular document — that is, distinct based on both `@type` and `@lang`. So in the example above the distinct items would be:

- txt
- gls[@lang='en']
- gls[@lang='tpi']
- msa

Ultimately I want to have a for-each loop that says for each `item` element that *should* be there (ie. the 4 listed above) create a paragraph, then go through each `morph` element and if the given item is there output its contents, if the item is not there, either output nothing or a placeholder text, depending on the item type. If an item type doesn't exist in the document, then there should be no paragraph for it.

I made a document that has everything working fine except the item types are hard-coded and it didn't take into account that there could be multiple items of the same type (but different lang). I can't hard-code the lang. The way I did it I think I need to totally rework it. I have been pathetically trying to copy examples from online of xsl:key and variables and other tricks, but I'm not getting it (I don't really know XSLT at all).

Desired output (simplified):

```
<word>
   <p type="txt" lang="tmy-Latn">ne-waŋ</p>
   <p type="gls" lang="en">3p.POSS-???</p>
   <p type="gls" lang="tpi>???-???</p>
   <p type="msa" lang="en">pro-noun</p>
</word>
<word>
   <p type="txt" lang="tmy-Latn">lil</p>
   <p type="gls" lang="en">go</p>
   <p type="gls" lang="tpi>???</p>
   <p type="msa" lang="en">verb</p>
</word>
```

Notice that the `morph` elements inside each word have been merged by item type/lang. If there is an empty or missing `item` of the four kinds expected for this document three question marks are inserted.

Example attempt based on Valdi_Bo's answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="itemTypes" match="//item" use="@type"/>
  <xsl:key name="items" match="//item" use="concat(@type, '/', @lang)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="keys" select="//morph/item[generate-id()=
        generate-id(key('items', concat(@type, '/', @lang))[1])]"/>

  <xsl:template match="word">
    <xsl:copy>


        <xsl:for-each select="//item[generate-id()=generate-id(key('itemTypes', @type)[1])]">
          <xsl:variable name="currentType" select="@type"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="//item[generate-id()=generate-id(key('items', concat($currentType, '/', @lang))[1])]">
                <p>
                    What do I put here?
                </p>    

          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: It would be useful if you will post your desired output in XML also.

Comment: Can you also edit your question to show the XSLT you have tried, even if it does need a re-work? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I thought about making an example output, but for some reason I didn't, I will update my answer.

Comment: I don't have any real XSLT to show. As I said, in my original document I just hard-coded each item type. Beyond that I have just been trying to get a grasp on XSL concepts and functions that seem related to what I want to do, without much success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find distinct item "keys" (type / lang) using the script given below.

For the presentation purpose, this script starts from printing of all "source"
items, ordered by *type* and *lang*.

Then there is the main part - creation of the item list (with unique *type*
/ *lang* attributes).

The final part contains 2 presentationa of the just created list.

- a single list,
- 2-level (type / language) list.

As far as source XML is concerned, I assumed that your `word` elements
are located in a **single** `root` tag, as XML format requires.
This is why my template matches just `root` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="itemTypes" match="//item" use="@type"/>
  <xsl:key name="items" match="//item" use="concat(@type, '/', @lang)"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- List source items, for test -->
      <xsl:for-each select="//item">
        <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@lang"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <!-- Create list of type / lang "keys" -->
      <xsl:variable name="keys" select="//item[generate-id()=
        generate-id(key('items', concat(@type, '/', @lang))[1])]"/>
      <!-- Show single list -->
      <items><xsl:copy-of select="$keys"/></items>
      <!-- Show 2-level (type / language) list -->
      <types>
        <xsl:for-each select="//item[generate-id()=
          generate-id(key('itemTypes', @type)[1])]">
          <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
          <xsl:variable name="currentType" select="@type"/>
          <Type><xsl:value-of select="$currentType"/></Type>
          <xsl:for-each select="//item[generate-id()=
            generate-id(key('items', concat($currentType, '/', @lang))[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="@lang"/>
            <Language><xsl:value-of select="@lang"/></Language>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </types>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/6q1R79v/1

From the above script you should use:

- The *Create list* section - to create the item list.
- Both "presentation" loops  (or maybe only the second loop) to
  generate required content for each type / language.

Comment: That's some fancy stuff there. And good to know about xsltransform.net. Why couldn't I find that when I was Googling for XML equivalents to jsfiddle.net? Unfortunately, it turns out I need an XSLT 1.0 solution for the system I'm working in. I have heard about the Muenchian Method, but I don't quite get it yet. Would I be able to create a key with that method just like you did with for-each-group? Also, once I have that handy key list how would I break apart the two parts of each key?o I guess what I really need is something that says "for each type { for each lang { do stuff } }".

Comment: I changed the example to **XSLT 1.0** version. Unfortunately, version 1.0 does not allow such constructs as *sequence of strings*, so the *keys* variable contains `item` elements.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can modify your example for my needs now. It is a shame it is so much uglier in XSLT 1.0. Maybe you could leave a 2.0 example as well, in case anybody else would find it useful.

Comment: Ack, I am still having trouble. I can do stuff inside the nested for-each loops, but it seems to only 'see' the key elements. When I am inside those loops how do I then get it to do something for each of the real items in each word of the document? (Either using apply-template, or more loops.) I have updated my question with an example of the desired output.